# Standalone IntelliTrace collected recording shows only external code

Tags: visual-studio, intellitrace

I am testing the standalone IntelliTrace recorder tool but struggle to use it for post-mortem debugging of a client WPF application.

I managed to record the data using the IntelliTrace recorder. However, when I view the created .itrace file in Visual Studio 2017 15.8.6 Enterprise, I cannot see any references to the code. VS tells me for all events that all threads execute only external or framework code.

[image: Visual Studio showing no source code]

The events that have been recorded are mostly WPF button click gestures. Even though the button click method itself is in BCL libraries, I was expecting to see click handler code. Furthermore, I also added a line to throw an exception in my app (which then of course is thrown in the code of the application), but for this, I also cannot see any code.

The collection plan did not make any difference. I was using the builtin ASP.NET Trace collection plan as it is supposed to be verbose, the default plan and a customized plan where I removed everything that is not important for the app under test.

The program database files are located next to the executables as I was executing the program from in its build output directory, so VS should not have any problems finding the pdbs.

The commandline I was using to start the collection is

```
C:\IntelliTrace\IntelliTraceSC.exe launch /cp:C:\IntelliTrace\collection_plan.ASP.NET.trace.xml /f:C:\IntelliTrace\test.itrace MyApp.exe
```

Am I missing something? What is required to see the actual code? Currently, I only see the sequence of events, which alone is pretty useless for debugging.

I am using the IntelliTrace collector version 14.0.24720.00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check your debbuger.
Try `Right click` on the `project` and under `Configuration Properties` -> `Debugging` there should be a row with `Debugger type`).

Can you try debugging with the type switched to `mixed mode`? It seems like you also have managed code running and it may be using the incorrect debugger if it is set to auto.

Are you still getting the same issue?

Also can you try debugging with Just My Code turned off. `Tools` -> `Optio` -> `Debugging`. Make sure `Enabled` Just My Code is `unchecked`. Does this issue still appear?

Also, try with:
`Debug` > `Options` > `General` > `Uncheck "Enable Just My Code"`

All the references that I mention has background in:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd264915(v=vs.120)

Hope it fix your issue

Comment: It was "Enable Just My Code", because I was opening the .itrace file in a blank VS, i.e. with no opened solution.